# How to draw text onto a jpg and resave it using system.drawing in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

Anyone have good example of how to write text onto a jpg image and resave it using System.Drawing in .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do it fairly easily...

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\test.jpg");
Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
string text = "Hello\nWorld";

gra.DrawString(text, new Font("Verdana", 24), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
bmp.Save("C:\\test_out.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across these, hope these help

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/TextOnImage.aspx

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image

Answer (score 1):

Acquire graphics from image calling CreateGraphics(), use its Graphics.DrawString method and save it as required.

More info: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx