# Image Annotation Alternatives on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, image

What are the alternatives to make annotations on images, using ASP.NET?

We are using http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage, but I wonder if there are free alternatives, or perhaps better.

Comment: You can draw the text onto the image yourself; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908631/how-to-draw-text-onto-a-jpg-and-resave-it-using-system-drawing-in-c-sharp for an example. Rather than save it to the file system, you could just write the result to the client.

Comment: That´s nice, but i need something ready to go...

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: I'm the author]

The [ImageResizing.Net library offers watermarking which can pull strings from the image querystring](http://imageresizing.net).

About 60% of the library is free and open-source (MIT style) - the core and about 20 plugins. The other 20 plugins are nearly as free (in terms of restrictions and source availability), but require inexpensive licenses.

Watermarking is part of the paid Design bundle, which includes 13 plugins and requires a $99 freelancer or $249 enterprise-wide license. The bundle includes PSD & RAW support, about 20 image filters, seam carving, automatic whitespace trimming, and a bunch of other features.

I think you'll find it is very competitive with Atalasoft's offerings for a fraction of the price. The source code for everything is [publicly downloadable](http://imageresizing.net/download) and permits modification and many kinds of redistribution.